# Create a Cell magics that Execute code before and after the cell execution

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython-magic

I have a special Class that capture and process the logs of a given algorithm. This looks like this

```
report = Report2File(logger,"./path")
report.start()

solveProblem()

report.stop()
del report
```

I would like to be event more lazy and write only

```
%%report "./path"
solveProblem()
```

The creation of such Magic Cell seams easy at first

UPDATED:

```
@magics_class
class MyMagics(Magics):

    @cell_magic
    def cmagic(self, line, cell):
        "my cell magic"
        self.before()
        exec(cell)
        self.after()
        return line, cell

    def before(self):
        do stuff ...

    def after(self):
        do stuff ...

ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(MyMagics)
```

However I get two issues:

1. I don't know how to pass the logger object to my magic
2. Jupyter keep telling me that the MyMagics module is not an ipython extension

### Partial Answer

[this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxkdO07L29Q) gives me the answer to 2.

Instead of

```
ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(MyMagics)
```

The correct way to register a Magic is the following

```
def load_ipython_extension(ip):
    ip.register_magics(MyMagics)

def unload_ipython_extension(ip):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to decorate the class with `@magics_class` (from IPython.core.magic).
To pass arguments, look at the `@magic_arguments` documentation for examples: it's pretty easy to follow.

Comment: `@magics_class` is necessary true but it is not enough to solve both issue. I just forgot to mentioned it. [this talk give me the answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxkdO07L29Q)